# Transforming a string using just recursion and the concatenation operator

Tags: haskell

I am doing the exercises in the book "The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming". In chapter 1, there is an exercise which asks to write a function which transforms a sequence of characters as follows: given a string "cab", transform it to "caabbb". I have come up with the solution below:

```
blowup :: String -> String                               
blowup [] = error "empty string"                         
blowup xs = blowuphelper xs 1                            

blowuphelper :: String -> Int -> String                  
blowuphelper [] 0 = error "empty string"                 
blowuphelper [x] y = replicate y x                       
blowuphelper (x:xs) y = replicate y x ++ (blowuphelper xs (y+1))
```

Since the book is introducing the language in chapter 1, it has only covered recursion so I have deliberately avoided using any higher order functions or techniques such as partially applying functions etc to produce an elegant solution. I have restricted myself to using recursion and the concatenation operator (++).

My question is if there is a better way of doing this. More specifically, is there a way of doing this using just recursion and the concatenation operator and  without using `replicate`. I could not find any way to do that. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use any higher order function, then you can solve this problem using explicit recursion:

```
transform :: String -> String
transform [] = []
transform xs = transformhelper 0 1 xs
  where
    transformhelper _ _ [] = []
    transformhelper 0 acc (x:xs) = x:transformhelper acc (acc + 1) xs
    transformhelper n acc (x:xs) = x:transformhelper (n - 1) acc (x:xs)
```

You can write the above code using `++`, but I think using `:` here is more efficient and natural.

Demo in ghci:

```
λ> transform "cab"
"caabbb"
```

Try to avoid using `error` in your function. If you want to indicate failure, then you are better off using `Maybe` or `Either` datatype.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to do it without resorting to a helper function? I tried to think of a way but couldn't find any. The main stumbling block being how to determine how many times to replicate a particular character.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to solve this without a helper function, but using a helper function isn't bad when it makes the code more clear to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement that `blowup` function by using only recursion and `(:)`:

```
blowup s = blowup' s 1
    where replicate 0 _ = []
          replicate n x = x : replicate (n-1) x
          blowup' [] _ = []
          blowup' (x:xs) n = replicate n x ++ blowup' xs (n+1)
```

For your reference, this function can also be implemented by using standard library function:

```
blowup = concat . zipWith replicate [1..]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the input list, you can do a stuctural recursion using head and tail.

Assume your list is `a: b: c: nil`

if you reverse it you can do 
structural induction on it

e.g.

Your list is now `c : b : a : nil`

Strucutural recursion using `(x:xs)` can be applied as

```hs
repeat c * 3(len xs+1) : repeat b * 2(len xs+1) : repeat a * 1(len xs+1) : repeat nil * 0
```

which gives you 
`cccbba`

and reverse this to get your answer (I have changed order of concatenation) - which is final blowup `answr : abbccc`

Here is the solution in terms haskell :

```hs
    blowup :: String -> String
    blowup "" = ""
    blowup xs = blowuprev (reverse xs) where blowuprev (x:xs) = blowuprev xs ++ replicate (length xs + 1) x
                                     blowuprev "" = ""
```